# Python. Вывести текст после разделителя

Tags: python-3.x

Есть файл test.txt

```
text0/text1
text5/text4
text8/text51
и тд
```

Хочу получить вывод вида:

```
text1
text4
text51
и тд
```

Пришел пока к такому:

```
with open(r"test.txt") as f_in, \
     open(r"final.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f_out:
     for line in f_in:
         s = line.split("/")[1]
         print(*s, sep='', end='', file=f_out)
```

На небольших файлах работает, проблем нет. Но на файлах 10GB+ получается больше часа времени.

Как вывести текст после разделителя более просто? Чтоб не разделять на части, а потом выводить кусок.

Comment: Попробую позже s = line.partition("/")[2] , возможно будет быстрее

Comment: Просто хочется уточнить, не делает ли этот код лишних действий, сначала разделяя строку на 2 части. Возможно есть способ считывать строку пока не обнаружжится разделитель и далее сразу удалять текст до разделителя, не разделяя текст на 2 части.

Comment: Вряд ли на питоне можно быстрее сделать. Подозреваю, что просто прочитать и записать такого размера файл на питоне будет почти так же медленно.

Answer (score 1):

Ты приблизился к пределу по скорости для интерпретируемых языков программирования с динамической типизацией, GIL-ом, сборщиком мусора и прочими плюшками. Для решения поставленной задачи рекомендую использовать компилируемый язык, а не питон. Например Си. Можешь попробовать ускорить код с помощью JIT или Cython, но т.к. в твоём коде в основном вызываются библиотечные функции, то, вероятно, не сильно выиграешь в скорости. Си, друг, да...только Си)

Comment: Ради интереса можно еще на ассемблере написать, ну и оптимизации ради опкодами прописать все команды (не ирония)

Comment: Просто хотел уточнить, не делает ли этот код "лишних" действий. Возможно быстрее будет, если будет считываться строка и как только обнаружится разделитель "/" код сразу выведет текст после "/" или удалит текст перед "/"